# Probability of a point from one normal distribution being higher than a point from another independent normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given two independent normal distributions:

Distribution 1: Mean $= 23.95$, SD $= 7.44$

Distribution 2: Mean $= 16.29$, SD $= 7.79$

How often on average will a point from Distribution 2 be greater than a point from Distribution 1?

I apologize for any nomenclature that is incorrect.

---

#### Progress

I know that the distribution of $Z=Y-X$ is normal, as well as its mean and variance.

Comment: Hint: Since the random variables are normal and independent, $Y-X$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu_Y-\mu_X$ and _variance_ $\sigma_Y^2+\sigma_X^2$. Do you know how to determine $P\{Y-X > 0\} = P\{Y > X\}$ from this knowledge about $Y-X$?

Comment: I see what you did with the inequality I think. So in this case the mean is 7.66 and the SD is 10.77? So Given this knowledge how do I determine how likely P{Y > X}. Would it help if I explained my practical reasoning for calculating this since I am such a stat. novice?

Comment: Write $Z=Y-X$. What do you know about the _distribution_ of $Z$? You know its mean and variance but what else? (Hint: read the _adjectives_ applied to the _object_ of the _verb_ **is** in the main clause of the first sentence in my previous comment). Then, read the second sentence of my previous comment, applying it to $Z$ about which you know, I hope, a lot by this time.

Comment: I know that the distribution of Z is normal, as well as its mean and variance. So the probablity of Z > 0 is equal to the probability of Y > X. I calculate this to be 0.238469339. Is this correct? Thanks so much Dilip for your help by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ X_1 \sim N(23.95,7.44), X_2 \sim N(16.29,7.79) $,

then, as mentioned by Dilip Sarwate in the comments, $ X_1 - X_2 \sim N(7.66,{\sqrt{7.44^2 + 7.79^2}}) $

Thus the problem becomes $$\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2) = \mathbb{P}(X<0),\ \ where \ \ X = X_1 - X_2 $$

This can be calculated directly or reverting to the standard $ N(0,1) $ distribution as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}( X  < 0 ) = \mathbb{P}(\frac{X-7.66}{{\sqrt{7.44^2 + 7.79^2}}}<\frac{-7.66}{\sqrt{7.44^2 + 7.79^2}})
\end{align}
$$

Noting that
 $$ \frac{X-7.66}{{\sqrt{7.44^2 + 7.79^2}}} = Z \sim N(0,1) $$

So the required probability is, approximately,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z<-0.7110976012) 
&= \mathbb{P}( Z > 0.7110976012) \\
&= 1 -\mathbb{P}(Z<0.7110976012) \\
&\approx 1 - 0.7611\\
&= 0.2389
\end{align}
$$

The numerical value found by looking  up  0.71  in  a [standard normal  table](http://figures.boundless.com/18108/full/normal01.jpe).

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for the help Daniel. So if I wanted to determine the probablity of X2 exceeding X1 by more than zero, I would just plug in a different number for X, I think. For example if I wanted to know the probability of X2 exceeding X1 by more than 7, I would plug in -7 for X correct? If I do this, my new z-score is -1.36 and therefore the P of X2 > X1 + 7 = .0869. Is this correct?

Comment: @RobbieTraylor That's right. $X_1 + 7 < X_2 \Leftrightarrow X_1 - X_2 + 7 < 0$ and we know that $X_1 - X_2 + 7 \sim N(7.66+7,{\sqrt{7.44^2 + 7.79^2}})$. Doing the same calculations as above yields the Z-score and probability you mention.

Comment: I'm really greatful to everyone who helped. I've got another problem about adding normal distributions, but I think it should probably have its own question.