# distribution of one normal RV's rank within another normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

This is a question originating from some research I'm doing on the discovery of correlations in a mass of time-series data.

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ that is normally distributed with mean $\mu_X$ and variance $\sigma^2_X$.  In addition, I have i.i.d. random variables $Y_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq n$) that are also normally distributed, but with mean $\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma^2_Y$.  Typically, $\mu_X > \mu_Y$, and we can assume that's the case in this question.

I'm interested in the distribution of $X$'s rank within the $Y_i$—effectively, the number of $Y_i$ that are greater than $X$.  Is there a straightforward way of obtaining even an approximate expression for this?

---

There is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071077/probability-of-a-point-from-one-normal-distribution-being-higher-than-a-point-fr), but I'm not sure that's really sufficiently close to the same question.  For one thing, it concerns only two samples, one drawn from each distribution, and for another, it gives only the probability that $X > Y$.  This is of limited use in determining the distribution of $X$'s rank, since the event $X > Y_i$ is not in general independent of the event $X > Y_j$.  However, if someone can articulate why an answer to that question will give me the answer to mine (or if there is another, more related question and answer), I'd be satisfied with that.

Comment: Let $W$ be the number of $Y_i$ greater than $X$. Then $W|X = x \sim \text{Binomial}(n, 1 - F_Y(x))$. So $\displaystyle \Pr\{W = w\} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \binom {n} {w} (1 - F_Y(x))^w F_Y(x)^{n-w} f_X(x)dx$. This is the pmf of $W$ theoretically, but need other to help to find a way to compute this (approximately) for you.

Comment: @BGM: Yes, sorry, I should've written the post to make it clear that I know how to obtain a theoretical expression of the kind you provide, but I would like something that is simpler to compute (and/or more intuitive) than integrating that numerically.  Thanks for the thoughts, though! :-)

Comment: After running a bunch of simulations in R, it looks like $W$ is beta distributed but I have not been able to show that yet.

Comment: @Therkel - your observation is intriguing.  Can you give more details?  In my mind, since shifting and rescaling obviously makes no difference, this problem has only two free parameters: i.e. without loss we can assume $\mu_X=1, \mu_Y=0$ and then we only worry about $\sigma_X, \sigma_Y$.  If $\sigma_X$ dominates, $X$ jumps all over the place and the rank is approx. bimodal at $0$ or $n$.  If $\sigma_Y$ dominates, then $Y$'s jump all over the place and $X$'s rank is approx binomial.  Intriguingly, beta distribution (with different $\alpha, \beta$) can cover both cases!

Comment: if we renormalize such that $\mu_X=1$ and $\mu_y=0$ then the answer has to be expressible as function of $\sigma_X$ and $\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}$

Comment: Maybe looking at order statistics asymptotics can help ?

Comment: @Thomas: Yeah, I have to revisit that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Emm, let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Let's first condition our computations on $X = x.$

Since $Y_i$s are normally distributed and i.i.d, we can compute 
$$p(x) = P(x \ge Y_i), Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2). $$

The function value of $p(x)$ can be efficiently computed. If you are concerned about the complexity in computing $p(x)$, you can try to search for approximate of the CDF function of normal distributions. I do not remember it on top of my head. But I'v seen some good approximation formulas.

Next, you mentioned that $Y_i$s are i.i.d. Hence
$$ P(X\ ranks\ k, 0\le k \le n \vert X=x) = \binom{n}{k}p(x)^{n-k}(1-p(x))^{k}. $$

Let $f(x)$ be the density function for $\mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$. Then
$$ P(X\ ranks\ k, 0\le k \le n) = \int \left( \binom{n}{k}p(x)^{n-k}(1-p(x))^{k} \right)f(x)dx. $$

To efficiently compute the above formula, especially for large $n$, one can note that the binomial distribution parameterized by $p(x)$ can be approximated by $\mathcal{N}(np(x), np(x)(1-p(x)))$. Refer to [this](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/NormalApprox.pdf) for details/proof.

Let $g(k;x) = \mathcal{N}(np(x), np(x)(1-p(x)))$, you further get
$$ P(X\ ranks\ k, 0\le k \le n) \approx \int g(k;x)f(x)dx. $$

I think most numerical computation packages can handle the above integration now. If desirable, each of the functions $p, f, g$ can be further approximated.

Comment: I don't think this works.  While $X, Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ are mutually independent, we do not have $Z_i$ and $Z_j$ being independent.  This was pointed out in the OP's last paragraph.  E.g. imagine $X, Y_i$ are all $\sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d., and further it turns out $Z_1 = 100$ (obviously a very, very low prob "event").  So either $X$ is abnormally large or $Y_1$ is abnormally small, or both.  If the former, $Z_2$ is likely to be also abnormally large, so $Z_2, Z_1$ are dependent.

Comment: @antkam   I did some simulation. It seems that Zhang's result does not match the simulation. By the way, BGM's expression match the simulation.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  In fact a clear contradiction happens when $X, Y_i$ are $N(0,1)$ i.i.d.  This wrong answer would have predicted that $X$'s rank is $Binomial(n, 1/2)$, but by symmetry (i.e. $X$ is just like any $Y_i$), clearly $X$'s rank is uniform in the range $[0, n]$.

Comment: @antkam corrected. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I'm going to award the bounty, though I'm not going to mark as answered, because I was looking for more of a tight approximation rather than a general integration approach (which I chose not to follow).  Thanks for the answer!